# Can't scroll tab-content and keep height at 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have the tab content scrollable and have the height be 100%.

There are a bunch of example on how to do this within a fixed height container, but I want the scroll window to be reactive to window resizing and resolution.

Basic problem: if you want to scroll tab content you need to set a height, if the viewing browsers resolution is less than set height, content will get cut off.

I have an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/wsadeh/4r5ye65x/2/

Is there anyway to make height 100%?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
      <li class="active">
       <a href="#tos" data-toggle="tab">TOS</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#privacy" data-toggle="tab">POS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tos">
        TOS... lots of text
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="privacy">
        POS... lots of text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
/* overflow works here, but scrolls page including tabs 
   overflow: auto; */
}
.tab-content{
/* this is where you would scroll only the content */
overflow:auto;  
/* need some kind of height - 100% doesn't work if you have a height like 600px and your resolution is smaller then content gets cut off */
height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the stuff above the tab content is a fixed height, you could use the CSS calc method with viewport height (vh) units.

```
.tab-content{
/* this is where you would scroll only the content */
overflow:auto;  
height: calc(100vh - 42px); /* Replace 42px with the needed height. 100vh means the whole height of the browser's viewport */
height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 42px);
height: -moz-calc(100vh - 42px);
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wt3hs15/1/
Please note that the pixel value in the calc function would need to be the pixel height of ALL the content that is above your tab content.

EDIT: For maximum compatibility, you probably also want to include prefixed versions of the calc function. Code edited to reflect this.

Comment: Well, yes, you can use any units you want with the calc function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc. However, you need the element's containing block to have a height specified as well to prevent the height from being set to auto. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height.

Comment: Is there a way we could modify the class `ant-tab-pane` so that we don't have to specify the height of tab?